# Are questions about choosing specific martial arts disciplines for fitness purposes in scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about choosing specific martial arts disciplines for fitness purposes in scope?

E.g. choosing one for a young child to improve hand-eye coordination and cardio fitness, with minimal impact stresses or injury risk (Aikido >> Karate).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specific tie-in to fitness it could be on-topic, but I would think that [martialarts.stackexchange.com](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/) would be a much better resource.

Answer (score -1):

Martial arts questions are on topic here, but something in the line of:

> *"Which martial art for a young child has the lowest injury risk?"*

Would likely sprout a lot of different opinions. As an answer to this question heavily depends on the coach, the specific style and lastly the child. There is no clear cut – *the one true* – answer to this.

I think all the factors that make up a **shopping recommendation** request are applicable here and by that it should be **off topic**.